# Responding to the user's input

Tags: python, input, wait

My code looks a bit like this:

```
question=input("What is your question?")

print("Let me think about that...")
import time
time.sleep(10) # delays for 10 seconds

print("I don't want to answer that question right now.")
print(question)

print("Ha ha ha")
```

and my problem is on the last line, because I don't know how to get the program to wait for the user to input their response before the program laughs. I assume it's something to do with the input function but I don't know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly... Shouldn't the following code solve your problem?

```py
question = input("What is your question? ")

print("Let me think about that...")
import time
time.sleep(10) # delays for 10 seconds

print("I don't want to answer that question right now.")
answer = input(question)

print("Ha ha ha")
```